Man helps a young woman escape from walled city; they embrace on a bridge and she ages and disintegrates into sand
The movie is a 70's or 80's movie. In a closing scene from the movie, which was very powerful, a man (the protagonist) who is in love with a woman that lives in the walled city (and I assume the wall is there to preserve the special powers of the people living there) helps her to escape so they can run away together. However as they embrace on the bridge outside the walled city, the effects of being on the outside take hold, she starts to age rapidly, and then disintegrates into sand. 
Hints:

The movie as I recall had a similar look and feel to Westworld
In my mind the leading male actor was Yul Brynner (but it wasn't)
I think the female lead actor had brown hair
it was set in a desert-like, somewhat Dune-like location

Please help me find the name of the movie.

@cde  No it isn't, and it's "Sodom". Lot's wife is turned to a pillar of salt, she doesn't crumble to dust and it happens because she looks back on the destruction of the city not because she has been removed from some prison.

It sounds a lot like She, the Rider Haggard story which has been made into films several times (in the '30s, the 60's and the '80s at least).

@matt thank you as well. However in She, the final scenes include fire and flames, unfortunately my memory dictates the end was not as violent, just a slow disintegration into dust. And certainly after having escaped a walled city. ☺

@Richard thank you, but not that one ☺

Could be an 1964 episode from Outer Limits called The Guest

the house is the lair of an amorphous, gelatinous alien being who is keeping the group of desperate humans suspended in time
As she realizes he will be trapped among them for eternity, she departs through the gate herself and, having eschewed her protection from the passage of time, withers and turns to dust.


Thank you Francisco, I have downloaded it and am watching it. I somehow recall the movie was in full colour however. Either way I am enjoying this episode!

@tonys You are welcome, please mark the question as answered if it is correct.

really enjoyed it, but, it's not the one I had in mind. The one I am after, there is literally an embrace, and she disintegrates while they are holding each other.

Possibly one of the film interpretations of Lost Horizon
Shangri-la is a walled city and the woman that leaves suddenly ages outside of its magical influence. I could only find a youtube link to the catastrophically awful 1973 (musical!) version where the woman ages, but no bridge is involved. 
Rapid Aging Scene from Lost Horizon 1973 
That said, there a multiple versions of the story in film, so it could be one of the others. 

I think this is heading in the right direction. But it's not the 1973 version. Do you know of any other ones along the Shangri-la trope filmed in colour? Thanks.

Any chance this was a foreign movie?

Hello there. Indeed it is possible that this was a foreign language film (well not English, at any rate!) I would have been in South Africa at the time. We sometimes got German or French movies.
